# Q: How to break a for loop inside a method?

Tags: java, loops, break

So I'm trying to find whether array a is a subset of array b, and my code is as follows :`

```
public class subset {
    public static boolean subset(int[]a, int[] b) {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;i<a.length;j++){
                if(a[i]==b[j]){
                    return true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int[] a = {1,2,6};
        int[] b = {1,2,4,3,7,4,8,5};
        if (subset(a,b))
            System.out.println("Array 1 is  contained  in Array 2");
        else
            System.out.println("Array 1 is not contained in Array 2");
    }
}
```

And I am getting the following errors: unreachable statement and missing return statement. 
What I want to do is that when the if condition is true it stops the inner for loop and carries on with the outer for loop.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An array is subset of another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628632/an-array-is-subset-of-another-array)

Comment: `return` exits from a method, which means any code placed after itin that method (here `break`) will not be executed which is why you see this error. Only exception is `finally` section if `return` was in `try` section.

Comment: Your inner loop is wrong; it counts up until `a.length` while you clearly want it to be counting up until `b.length` since the variable `j` loops through `b`, not `a`.

Answer (score 0):

2 things need to be fixed. You need to remove `break`, and add a `return false` at the end.

```
public static boolean subset(int[]a, int[] b) {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<a.length;j++){
            if(a[i]==b[j]){
                return true;
                //break; remove this
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //add this
}
```

Also, you could simplify it a bit, by doing this, instead of the `if..else`

```
return a[i]==b[j];
```

Comment: That still won't work, as if the i=2 and the j=1 it will return false without checking the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is this:

```
return true;
break;}
```

the second line will never be executed because the first one terminates the method execution. Decide which line you want here: return a value or jump out of the inner loop (neither I presume, this branch should be empty, see below).

The second problem is that when you pass in an empty array the loops are not executed and the method does not have a value to return. Here simply add a "return true" (or false, quite arbitrary here) at the end of the method.

You probably can simplify the loop body in this way:

```
if(a[i]!=b[j]){
    return false;
}
```